# Please help identify a set with bag of tan, white, grey, and light-blue 1x1 and 1x2 bricks?

Tags: set-identification

[image: small bag]

Help me identify what set this small bag goes to?

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I bought a used 10214 London Tower Bridge. It came with all parts in one single bag. However, looking at the brick types and colors on the picture I would guess it is from 10214.